# Android merge adapter adding a view from an xml

Tags: android

hi i'm trying to add a view to a merge adapter and i'm not entirely sure as to how to do. i'm wanting to add a header bar in between two lists. so far i have3 arrayadapters that populate one list im wanting to add a header between each one. i have a .xml layout that i want to use for the header or would it be better to programmatically write the layout.

heres my as to what i have tried so far but keep getting errors when i scroll it crashes the app. hopefully i have made this clear enough as  i think its really useful to learn this.

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList);
    arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList2);
    arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList3);


     RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);

        ImageView mImage = new ImageView(this);
        mImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.titlerect);        
        //layout.addView(mImage,labelLayoutParams);





     //RelativeLayout rc = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.redcelllayout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = 
                   (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View Header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.redcell, layout, true);



    setListAdapter (arrayAdapter);

       ListView list = getListView();
       list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        adapter = new MergeAdapter();
        adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        adapter.addView(mImage);
        adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

        adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

and heres the xml layout for the header bar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/redcelllayout" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/titlerect" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/redheadertext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

also heres the error im getting

```
05-11 09:51:06.187: E/AndroidRuntime(8598): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
05-11 09:51:06.187: E/AndroidRuntime(8598):     at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1834)
05-11 09:51:06.187: E/AndroidRuntime(8598):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1803)
05-11 09:51:06.187: E/AndroidRuntime(8598):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
05-11 09:51:06.187: E/AndroidRuntime(8598):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:641)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_name, null);
    lv.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

where lv is listview.

add your header before setting adapter.

Comment: thanks for this. just one thing when i scroll the header views scroll separately to the lists how can i make it so they stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams..FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

instead of

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

This is causing ClassCastException as shown in stacktrace

Comment: hi thank you for your help however it still crashes. would my setContentView layout affect this?

Comment: no it will not affect your setContentView.. please update latest stacktrace so that we can find out the cause behind crashing